# Cannot install Oppia

Tags: java, python, python-2.7, zip

When I try to do the install process of Oppia, an error message is thrown:

```
    Building languages list.
Compiling repl.coffee.
   minifying tmp/jsrepl.js using java -Xmx1g -jar ./tools/closure-compiler/trunk/build/compiler.jar --compilation_level SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS --js
Done.
Downloading file yuicompressor-2.4.8.jar to ../oppia_tools/yuicompressor-2.4.8
Downloading file ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.js to ./third_party/static/ui-bootstrap-0.10.0
Downloading file ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.min.js to ./third_party/static/ui-bootstrap-0.10.0
Downloading file jquery.js to ./third_party/static/jquery-2.0.3
Downloading file jquery.min.js to ./third_party/static/jquery-2.0.3
Downloading file jquery.min.map to ./third_party/static/jquery-2.0.3
Downloading file jquery-ui.min.js to ./third_party/static/jqueryui-1.10.3
Downloading file angular.js to ./third_party/static/angularjs-1.2.0-rc.3
Downloading file angular.min.js to ./third_party/static/angularjs-1.2.0-rc.3
Downloading file angular.min.js.map to ./third_party/static/angularjs-1.2.0-rc.3
Downloading file angular-resource.js to ./third_party/static/angularjs-1.2.0-rc.3
Downloading file angular-resource.min.js to ./third_party/static/angularjs-1.2.0-rc.3
Downloading file angular-resource.min.js.map to ./third_party/static/angularjs-1.2.0-rc.3
Downloading file angular-route.js to ./third_party/static/angularjs-1.2.0-rc.3
Downloading file angular-route.min.js to ./third_party/static/angularjs-1.2.0-rc.3
Downloading file angular-route.min.js.map to ./third_party/static/angularjs-1.2.0-rc.3
Downloading file angular-sanitize.js to ./third_party/static/angularjs-1.2.0-rc.3
Downloading file angular-sanitize.min.js to ./third_party/static/angularjs-1.2.0-rc.3
Downloading file angular-sanitize.min.js.map to ./third_party/static/angularjs-1.2.0-rc.3
Downloading file angular-mocks.js to ./third_party/static/angularjs-1.2.0-rc.3
Downloading file angular-scenario.js to ./third_party/static/angularjs-1.2.0-rc.3
Downloading file d3.min.js to ./third_party/static/d3js-3.2.8
Downloading and unzipping file select2-3.4.1 to ./third_party/static
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scripts/install_third_party.py", line 260, in <module>
    SELECT2_ZIP_ROOT_NAME, SELECT2_TARGET_ROOT_NAME)
  File "scripts/install_third_party.py", line 83, in download_and_unzip_files
    with zipfile.ZipFile(TMP_UNZIP_PATH, 'r') as z:
AttributeError: ZipFile instance has no attribute '__exit__'
```

I cannot really understand the error message. Should I install some package (for ZIP)?

Comment: What version of Python are you using? Your tag says 2.7 but are you certain? That error message suggests an earlier version of Python. You can double-check at the command line with `python --version`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you (or the installer) actually running Python 2.7?

The line: `with zipfile.ZipFile(TMP_UNZIP_PATH, 'r') as z:` is a `with` statement and it requires ZipFile instances to support the context manager interface, namely `__enter__()` and `__exit__()` methods need to be defined.

Context manager support for ZipFile was added in version 2.7, and for Python 3 it was added in 3.2. You are not using the correct Python version.

Comment: Got it! I just forget to change the default version of the Python. `sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python` It works now.